# Get the count of the latest statusbar notifications in Android

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, launcher, google-tv

I have a Google TV and find the Home app can display the count of the latest statusbar notifications. Does anyone know how to implements this function?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the count of notifications sent from other apps in Android. Only system apps can do that. You could keep track of the number of notifications that your app is sending but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: So do you think the home app shouldn't be replaced?

Comment: And what our custom Home app needs is only the count of the latest notification, not the content of the notifications

Comment: Could any one answer my question?