# Keep track of notifications

Tags: android

I want to be able to keep track of the number of active notifications on a phone. To start it could just be unread sms and emails, but eventually i would like to include other notifications. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is my answer below an answer to your question? If so, please accept/upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you cannot get the number of active notifications on a phone.

See also this answer:
[Get the count of the latest statusbar notifications in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996849/get-the-count-of-the-latest-statusbar-notifications-in-android)